# Can't change color of List item when using .addClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the color of my navbar list items on scroll, using jQuery .addClass, I have successsfully changed the logo and background color of the header, but i am stuck on this part. The html looks like this:

```
 <nav id="tf-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="logo">
      <a class="navbar-brand white-logo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logoNewRev.png" alt="purus consultants logo" ></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand scrolling-logo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logoNew2.png" alt="purus consultants logo" ></a>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li role="presentation" ><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"class="active"><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li role="presentation" ><a href="./Implementation.html">implementation</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation" ><a href="./Training.html">training</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation" ><a href="./Support.html">support</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="contacts.html">contact</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="community.html">community</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="news.html">news</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="FAQ's.html">faq's</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The css is this:

```
#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dark > li {
color: black !important;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

And the jQuery is this:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var navHeight = $(window).height() - 140;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('on');
        $('#tf-menu.navbar-default.navbar-nav > li').addClass('dark');
        $('.logo').addClass('scrolling');

    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('on');
        $('#tf-menu.navbar-default.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('dark');
        $('.logo').removeClass('scrolling');

    }
});
```

This works when adding the class' .on and .scroling, and i can see that it adds .dark to the list items so i am thnking that the css is wrong, but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tf-menu.navbar-default.navbar-nav > li').addClass('dark');
```

This says the element with id tf-menu which also has class navbar-default and also has class navbar-nav with a direct child of li. Perhaps try:

```
$('#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav').addClass('dark');

#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav.dark > li > a {
color: black !important;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or if you are trying to turn individual Lis dark

```
$('#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li').addClass('dark');

#tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dark > a {
color: black !important;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Targeting the anchor in the selector since the anchors may ignore their parents color.

Comment: Thanks for the response, just tried both of those with no success, in fact using Firefox inspector i can see that using the jQuery suggested, it stops adding the class .dark to the li.  So i think the jQuery is right, so that leaves the CSS

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to add change the color of the text inside each li?

Comment: Ok so the idea is that on scroll, the background color of the header turns white, the logo changes color and each li in the nav turns black. before scroll the background of the header is transparent and the li are all white.

Comment: Well color style changes the color of text. If you want to change the li to have a background color of black you should use background-color.

Comment: AtheistP3ace its the color of the font i want to change not the background, I have already figured out the logo and header background part, and they work fine, but its just these pescy li

Comment: OK, sorry just trying to clear that up. It may be the links are ignoring the color from their parent. If you are putting the class dark on each li you could try changing the class selector to: #tf-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dark > a

Comment: AtheistP3ace why didnt i see that! this worked thanks dude!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! I'll update my answer to say that.

Comment: And not to bother you, if it's not too much trouble would you accept my answer as the answer you wanted? Trying to earn reputation points for more privileges on site. Thanks!